# How to set lumo dark theme as base theme and then override using custom theme

Tags: java, vaadin

I want to have lumo dark theme as default theme and then in some aspect modify components using my custom theme. I have the theme set using `@Theme("myTheme")` and I think it should be possible to set parent theme using `theme.json` and setting the parent parameter but I cannot find out if this is correct or how to do this properly.

EDIT: I followed the advice from the accepted answer and here is the resulting "dark" theme containing the exact same values for lumo-dark:

```
html {
    /* Base (background) */
    --lumo-base-color: hsl(214, 35%, 21%);

    /* Tint */
    --lumo-tint-5pct: hsla(214, 65%, 85%, 0.06);
    --lumo-tint-10pct: hsla(214, 60%, 80%, 0.14);
    --lumo-tint-20pct: hsla(214, 64%, 82%, 0.23);
    --lumo-tint-30pct: hsla(214, 69%, 84%, 0.32);
    --lumo-tint-40pct: hsla(214, 73%, 86%, 0.41);
    --lumo-tint-50pct: hsla(214, 78%, 88%, 0.5);
    --lumo-tint-60pct: hsla(214, 82%, 90%, 0.58);
    --lumo-tint-70pct: hsla(214, 87%, 92%, 0.69);
    --lumo-tint-80pct: hsla(214, 91%, 94%, 0.8);
    --lumo-tint-90pct: hsla(214, 96%, 96%, 0.9);
    --lumo-tint: hsl(214, 100%, 98%);

    /* Shade */
    --lumo-shade-5pct: hsla(214, 0%, 0%, 0.07);
    --lumo-shade-10pct: hsla(214, 4%, 2%, 0.15);
    --lumo-shade-20pct: hsla(214, 8%, 4%, 0.23);
    --lumo-shade-30pct: hsla(214, 12%, 6%, 0.32);
    --lumo-shade-40pct: hsla(214, 16%, 8%, 0.41);
    --lumo-shade-50pct: hsla(214, 20%, 10%, 0.5);
    --lumo-shade-60pct: hsla(214, 24%, 12%, 0.6);
    --lumo-shade-70pct: hsla(214, 28%, 13%, 0.7);
    --lumo-shade-80pct: hsla(214, 32%, 13%, 0.8);
    --lumo-shade-90pct: hsla(214, 33%, 13%, 0.9);
    --lumo-shade: hsl(214, 33%, 13%);

    /* Contrast */
    --lumo-contrast-5pct: var(--lumo-tint-5pct);
    --lumo-contrast-10pct: var(--lumo-tint-10pct);
    --lumo-contrast-20pct: var(--lumo-tint-20pct);
    --lumo-contrast-30pct: var(--lumo-tint-30pct);
    --lumo-contrast-40pct: var(--lumo-tint-40pct);
    --lumo-contrast-50pct: var(--lumo-tint-50pct);
    --lumo-contrast-60pct: var(--lumo-tint-60pct);
    --lumo-contrast-70pct: var(--lumo-tint-70pct);
    --lumo-contrast-80pct: var(--lumo-tint-80pct);
    --lumo-contrast-90pct: var(--lumo-tint-90pct);
    --lumo-contrast: var(--lumo-tint);

    /* Text */
    --lumo-header-text-color: var(--lumo-contrast);
    --lumo-body-text-color: var(--lumo-contrast-90pct);
    --lumo-secondary-text-color: var(--lumo-contrast-70pct);
    --lumo-tertiary-text-color: var(--lumo-contrast-50pct);
    --lumo-disabled-text-color: var(--lumo-contrast-30pct);

    /* Primary */
    --lumo-primary-color: hsl(214, 90%, 48%);
    --lumo-primary-color-50pct: hsla(214, 90%, 70%, 0.69);
    --lumo-primary-color-10pct: hsla(214, 90%, 55%, 0.13);
    --lumo-primary-text-color: hsl(214, 90%, 77%);
    --lumo-primary-contrast-color: #fff;

    /* Error */
    --lumo-error-color: hsl(3, 79%, 49%);
    --lumo-error-color-50pct: hsla(3, 75%, 62%, 0.5);
    --lumo-error-color-10pct: hsla(3, 75%, 62%, 0.14);
    --lumo-error-text-color: hsl(3, 100%, 80%);

    /* Success */
    --lumo-success-color: hsl(145, 72%, 30%);
    --lumo-success-color-50pct: hsla(145, 92%, 51%, 0.5);
    --lumo-success-color-10pct: hsla(145, 92%, 51%, 0.1);
    --lumo-success-text-color: hsl(145, 85%, 46%);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may have to continue the same way.  This means, you would have to
switch to the `dark` variant too in your theme.

E.g. add `@Theme(value = 'app-theme', variant = "dark")` and then add in
your `frontend/themes/app-theme/styles.css` something like:

```css
[theme~="dark"] {
    --lumo-base-color: hsl(0, 0%, 0%);
    --lumo-primary-color: hsl(122, 96%, 47%);
    --lumo-primary-color-50pct: hsl(122, 96%, 47%, 0.5);
    --lumo-primary-color-10pct: hsl(122, 96%, 47%, 0.1);
}
```

Then continue to do so for the components (add `[theme~="dark"]`); you
might want to have a peek at the browser dev-console to make sure, you
are getting the overrides right.

You could start from the dark theme `--lumo...` vars in your own theme
and hope, that the calculations work down all the way; but there are
optimizations for `dark` all over the place, and IMHO you are better off
doing it this way.

Comment: Actually it's not necessary to prefix your own styles with [theme~="dark"] as long as your selectors have higher specificity than the Lumo defaults, since component default styles mostly don't use that theme attribute themselves, they just consume Lumo style properties whose default values are set with that attribute in the dark theme.